# How to position Horizontal Ray text from PDH & PDL to bottom right

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to position my text label to far right of screen like you would do if you clicked on a horizontal ray and went to settings and positioned text to bottom right.

This is my code so far but text is in center and moves when I zoom in and out

```
//@version=5
indicator('PRIOR D/W/M LEVELS', shorttitle='D/W/M', overlay=true)

preDayData = input(defval=true, title='Previous Day High/Low?', tooltip='Select to show previous days high and low values across all timeframes')
preWeekData = input(defval=true, title='Previous Week High/Low?', tooltip='Select to show previous weeks high and low values across all timeframes')
preMonthData = input(defval=true, title='Previous Month High/Low?', tooltip='Select to show previous month high and low values across all timeframes')

PDH = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[1])
PDL = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[1])
PWH = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', high[1])
PWL = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', low[1])
PMH = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'M', high[1])
PML = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'M', low[1])

is_new_day = ta.change(time('1W'))
bar_idx_prev_day = bar_index - ta.valuewhen(is_new_day, bar_index+5, 1)
is_new_week = ta.change(time('1W'))
bar_idx_prev_week = bar_index - ta.valuewhen(is_new_week, bar_index+5, 1)
is_new_month = ta.change(time('1M'))
bar_idx_prev_month = bar_index - ta.valuewhen(is_new_month, bar_index+5, 1)



var line l_pdh = na
var line l_pdl = na
var line l_pwh = na
var line l_pwl = na
var line l_pmh = na
var line l_pml = na

// if barstate.islast
if preDayData == true
    l_pdh := line.new(bar_index - bar_idx_prev_day, PDH, bar_index, PDH, extend=extend.right, color=color.blue)
    l_pdl := line.new(bar_index - bar_idx_prev_day, PDL, bar_index, PDL, extend=extend.right, color=color.blue)
    
if preWeekData == true
    l_pwh := line.new(bar_index - bar_idx_prev_week, PWH, bar_index, PWH, extend=extend.right, color=color.yellow)
    l_pwl := line.new(bar_index - bar_idx_prev_week, PWL, bar_index, PWL, extend=extend.right, color=color.yellow)

if preMonthData == true
    l_pmh := line.new(bar_index - bar_idx_prev_month, PMH, bar_index, PMH, extend=extend.right, color=color.fuchsia)
    l_pml := line.new(bar_index - bar_idx_prev_month, PML, bar_index, PML, extend=extend.right, color=color.fuchsia)


plotshape(preDayData ? PDH : na, location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, textcolor=color.new(color.blue,0), color=color.new(color.blue,100), text="Daily High", show_last=1, offset=5)
plotshape(preDayData ? PDL : na, location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, textcolor=color.new(color.blue,0), color=color.new(color.blue,100), text="Daily Low", show_last=1, offset=5)
plotshape(preWeekData ? PWH : na, location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, textcolor=color.new(color.yellow,0), color=color.new(color.yellow,100), text="Weekly High", show_last=1, offset=15)
plotshape(preWeekData ? PWL : na, location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, textcolor=color.new(color.yellow,0), color=color.new(color.yellow,100), text="Weekly Low", show_last=1, offset=15)
plotshape(preMonthData ? PMH : na, location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, textcolor=color.new(color.fuchsia,0), color=color.new(color.fuchsia,100), text="Monthly High", show_last=1, offset=25)
plotshape(preMonthData ? PML : na, location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, textcolor=color.new(color.fuchsia,0), color=color.new(color.fuchsia,100), text="Monthly Low", show_last=1, offset=25)

line.delete(l_pdh[1])
line.delete(l_pdl[1])
line.delete(l_pwh[1])
line.delete(l_pwl[1])
line.delete(l_pmh[1])
line.delete(l_pml[1])
```

I would like it to look more like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not quite possible.

As a workaround, you can plot the values instead of using lines `with show_last=1` and `trackprice=true`, and turn on the option to display the plot name and values on the price scale.

Here is an example for the daily high.

```
//@version=5
indicator('PRIOR D/W/M LEVELS', shorttitle='D/W/M', overlay=true)

preDayData = input(defval=true, title='Previous Day High/Low?', tooltip='Select to show previous days high and low values across all timeframes')
PDH = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[1])
plot(preDayData ? PDH : na, " Daily High", color.blue, show_last=1, trackprice=true)
```

[image]